# WPF - Retrieve the object binded instead of a single property of the object

Tags: wpf, checkbox, binding, textblock

I have  a checkbox and a textblock inside a stackpanel. When the textblock  is clicked, the checkbox should be checked. Actually, it is a set of checkboxes and set of text blocks. Need to retrieve the value **ID** ( this is a property of the class "**SomeClass**" of the checkbox. But what has been binded to the Textblock is the **name**. My question is how do I retrieve the the whole object ?

```
  <ListView>
     <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn>
               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding SomeClass} ">
                              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                  <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>

                                        <CheckBox...../>
                                        <TextBlock ...Text={Binding Name}/>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                  </DataTemplate>
                               </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                           </ItemsControl>
                       </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn>                     
      </GridView>
    </ListView>
```

I am making use of the **MouseLeftButton** event of TextBlock. I can retrieve the Name, but what I need is the whole obect itself so that I can retrieve the ID property . Any solution to this ?

Comment: To get current `DataContext`, which will be your item, in the event handler do something like `(YourItemType)(((TextBlock)sender).DataContext)`

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough ! Thanks a million and yes, it works !

Answer (score 0):

Use {Binding} without a property path or {Binding Path=.}

Comment: I forgot to mention that TextBlock's Text property displaying Name is necessary. In that case, have to use {Binding Name}.  If I'm correct, Using {Binding Path= } does not display the Name in the TextBlock's Text property...ryt ?

Comment: Of course not but the answer was based on retrieving the whole object. Where is it that you require the whole object?

Comment: I have a "MouseDownEvent" on "TextBlock". There I need to have the ID property of SomeClass . That is why I am thinking whether there is a way to access the object so that I can access the ID property in it.

Comment: You should just be able to use {Binding Name} for the text and {Binding Id} elsewhere within the TextBlock. The TextBlock data context is set to the item so you can access any property you want.